# how to modify orbitcontrols to allow infinite vertical rotation

Tags: three.js

I'm using orbitcontrols with an orthographic camera due to orthographictrackballcontrols issues (biggest issue is scene will randomly disappear completely).  OrbitControls works exactly as I need it to except for the vertical rotation limitation.  I see the following code:

```
this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians
```

I tried changing these to infinity and -infinity, but it doesn't work.  These variables are used here:

```
spherical.phi = Math.max( scope.minPolarAngle, Math.min( scope.maxPolarAngle, spherical.phi ) );
```

I don't see what is limiting the infinite vertical rotation...Any way to allow this functionality without using trackballcontrols?

Comment: The line after the one you are referencing is calling ```spherical.makeSafe();```. Which restricts the polar angle to be between 0.000001 and pi - 0.000001. See [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Spherical) for reference.

Comment: removing that line doesn't work either... same behavior except the camera begins to switch rapidly when at the 0 or PI locations